# Red eyed monster with gaze that turns you into a wooden doll?

Tags: story-identification, movie, episode-identification

Back in the early to mid 90s, my mom was channel surfing and stopped on something where some people were investigating missing kids and these wooden dolls were showing up.

One kid decided to go out at night and was playing on a roof or something and slipped, luckily a hand caught him, unluckily it was a monster who had glowy red eyes and poof the kid gets turned into a wooden doll. And poof my mom decided this was not toddler friendly and changed the channel.

Now I was a toddler at the time so I could get details wrong, but to me the wooden dolls looked more like a table leg or bedpost you'd make on a lathe than a real humanoid figure.

The monster seemed to have a beast style face, but was maybe cloaked up in black, when older one illustrated version of Robin Hood's Guy of Gisbourne wearing a pile of hide for a cloak reminded me of this monster.

I don't know if this is a movie or tv episode and based on so many kids being on cast it would not surprise me if this an episode of an anthology like "whats the story wishbone" but I did not see it there.

Comment: So not [*Ernest Scared Stupid*](https://moviesfilmsandflix.com/2016/10/24/ernest-scared-stupid-the-story-of-a-snot-nosed-troll-that-wrecked-my-youth/).

Comment: Was this live-action or animated?  What language was it in?

Comment: Live action, English

Comment: @fuzzyboots, the timeframe matches, and the plot matches the snippet of what I saw.

Maybe the design isn't totally there, but then again I saw a few scenes on a small 90's tv as a toddler so....

I'll have to watch the whole thing,

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Not_a_monster: I went ahead and posted that as an answer. If you watch the film and it is a match, you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

I posted this as a comment, since it didn't seem to match on most of the details, but since you said in the comments that it may be a match, *[Ernest Scared Stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Scared_Stupid)* does involve children being turned into wooden dolls, albeit not shaped in the way you say.

> In the late 19th century, the demonic troll Trantor transforms children into wooden dolls to feast upon their energy in Briarville, Missouri. The townsfolk capture him and seal him under an oak tree, with Phineas Worrell, one of the village elders and an ancestor of Ernest P. Worrell, establishing the seal. Trantor vengefully places a curse on the Worrell family, stating that he can only be released on the night before Halloween by a Worrell. As part of the curse, every generation of Worrells will get "dumber and dumber and dumber", until the dumbest member of the family is foolish enough to release him from his earthly prison.

There's a longer review [here](https://moviesfilmsandflix.com/2016/10/24/ernest-scared-stupid-the-story-of-a-snot-nosed-troll-that-wrecked-my-youth/) with several clips, including the one that follows of doll transformations:

### Clips of the children being turned into dolls

The child falling is likely the first one transformed, [Joey](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Ernest_Scared_Stupid).

> Joey is going home from the tree house and falls into a muddy hole. While trying to get out, he reaches his hand and Trantor grabs it. He first disguises his voice as Ernest's, and then transforms Joey into his first wooden doll.